# Unity MecAnim Bones

Tags: unity

Has anybody here used motion data to apply to mecanim and animate a Unity character with it?

I have a motion capture device that streams in live motion data into Unity, through a plug-in. It's called Xsens MVN.

I would like to be able to dampen some movements, exaggerate some, mirror some, etc...

Is it possible to programmatically modify what will be applied to MecAnim? If yes, where do I start?

For example, I want the character to be, as usual, animated by the motion data coming into Unity, but I want his right arm to move faster.

There are a lot of tutorials, but mainly to do with applying animations and work flows and parameters, so I would appreciate any tips on how to start off with modifying individual bones, etc...